# How to throw an error in an embedded form's post validator (sfForm)

Tags: php, symfony1, symfony-1.4, symfony-forms

With Symfony 1.4's Forms, how can I throw a sfValidatorError in the post validator of an embedded form?

My parent form calls the following:

```
public function configure(){
    $this->embedForm('page', $pageLinkForm);
}
```

And my embedded form:

```
public function configure(){
    $this->validatorSchema->setPostValidator(new sfValidatorCallback(array(
        'callback' => array($this, 'validateLink')
    )));
}

public function validateLink($validator, $values) {
    if (!empty($values['link']) && !empty($values['outside_link']))
        throw new sfValidatorError($validator, 'Only specify either an internal link or an external link, but not both.');

}
```

The post validator runs validateLink which throws sfValidatorError but it does not show up as a global error and the form isValid(), but it shouldn't be.

Why is the error ignored? How can I make it not ignored?

Comment: Try debbuging this file : http://trac.symfony-project.org/browser/branches/1.4/lib/validator/sfValidatorSchema.class.php (doing step by step debugging with XDebug if you can, with var_dump() otherwise), to check that:

 - The error sfValidatorError is caught
   on line 194 during embed form post
   validation
 - The resulting errorSchema is thrown on line 199
 - It is caught again on line 159 in the parent form
And please post a var_dump() of your parent form's validatorSchema

Answer (score 2):

IMHO it's better to throw a sfValidatorSchemaError, like this :

```
$error =  new sfValidatorError($validator, 'invalid', array('value' => $field_name));
throw new sfValidatorErrorSchema($validator, array($field_name => $error));
```

And if you want to throw an error inside an embedded form, just embed the sfValidatorSchemaError :

```
//define container
$errorSchema =  new sfValidatorErrorSchema($validator);

//embedded field error
$error =  new sfValidatorError($validator, 'invalid', array('value' => $field_name));
$errorSchema->addError($error, $field_name);

//associate $errorSchema to your embedded field
throw new sfValidatorErrorSchema($validator, array('page' => $errorSchema));
```

Answer (score 0):

in sf1.1 I do it like this:

```
 public function bind(array $taintedValues = null, array $taintedFiles = null)
 {
   sfLoader::loadHelpers(array('I18N'));
   parent::bind($taintedValues, $taintedFiles);
   if($taintedValues["password"])
   {
     if(!$taintedValues["pwd_verify"])
     {
       $this->getErrorSchema()->addError(new sfValidatorError(new sfValidatorSchema(), __('Please reenter the new password.')), 'password');
     }
   }
 }
```

I hope it helps you.